# Exclude a transit agency in Bing Maps API

Tags: routes, maps, bing-maps, bing, transit

How do I exclude a transit agency in Bing Maps API route calculation?

E.g. Bing Maps include "Go Transit" as a local transit option. In fact Go transit in Toronto is more like a regional transit between cities.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it. Here is the answer from MSDN:

[MSDN answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a220aac9-5d17-416b-be0b-dd34ffc4eee1/exclude-a-transit-agency-in-bing-maps-api?forum=bingmapsservices#a220aac9-5d17-416b-be0b-dd34ffc4eee1)